# Robust Hausman vs Mundlak test to choose between FE and RE model?

Tags: mixed-model, econometrics, panel-data, stata, hausman

What is the difference between robust Hausman test and Mundlak test?

Wooldridge *"Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data" (Second edition page 870)* mentions robust Hausman test is obtained by adding group averages to RE estimation and testing for joint significance.

Isn't Mundlak test also the same see [statapost](https://blog.stata.com/2015/10/29/fixed-effects-or-random-effects-the-mundlak-approach/) ie; RE estimation with panel level means and covariates, and a similar joint hypothesis on the regression coefficient for panel level means.

Also, does xtoverid module in stata software follow the same methdology?